# PHP mysql to mysqli migration issues (custom functions, procedural style)

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, database-connection

Goodmorning

I'm planning to migrate a whole application I made from mysql extension to mysqli, due to next PHP version will not support mysql anymore and I don't want to go fool in the last minutes.

At the moment all page have 2 main inclusions:
1) dbdata.inc.php which contains database connection data
2) function.inc.php which contains most used functions

I'd like to mantain the procedural style also using mysqli extension, but I read that all mysqli functions must receive the connection link as a parameter.

I'm asking for suggestion on the best way (i.e. the most painless solution) to migrate without going mad and without radically rewrite all my php pages.

Actual content of **dbdata.inc.php**:

```
$yare_db = mysql_connect($yaredb_host,$yaredb_user,$yaredb_pass) or die("some error warning<br>"); 
mysql_select_db($yaredb_conn); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Most used functions defined in functions.inc.php:

```
function YQUERY($query) {
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return $res;
}

function FETCHA($res) {
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    return $rs;
}

function NUMROWS($res) {
    $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
    return $num;
}

function AFFROWS() {
    $num = mysql_affected_rows();
    return $num;
}

/* an important function filtering user input texts before passing them to queries */

function msg_safe($string) {
    // some regex and \n to "<br>" substitutions...
    $string = mysql_real_escape($string);
    return $string;
}
```

Well, the question now is how to migrate:

1) Should i pass the db connection as a function parameter? I.e. something like:

```
function YQUERY($link,$query) {
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    return $res;
}
```

?

2) Should I, instead, define the db connection (defined into included dbdata.inc.php at page start) as GLOBAL variable, inside the function? I.e. something like:

```
function YQUERY($query) {
     global $link;
     $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
     return $res;
}
```

?

3) Should I (it sounds terrific) explicitly declare a new connection inside any custom function? I.e. something like:

```
function YQUERY($query) {
     $link = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
     $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
     return $res;
}
```

?

4) Other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Option 2 would be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't so many connections in your application, the option of GLOBAL $link is the best.
If you have so much connections, i think you must do a function to open connection, and other function that close the connection, and when you do something in DB open the connection, do all that you need to do, and close the connection.

Comment: Actually, using good old mysql extension, the structure used in every page is this:

Comment: The structure used in every page is this:
`
-- Beginning of page: inclusion of dbdata.inc.php where a connection to db is opened 

(
code 
)

-- end of page: inclusion of dbclose.inc.php, a file which closes the connection
`

A friend of mine told me that closing explicitly the connection is someway useless, unless in pages doing some hard mantainance cronjobs. We expect to have a maximum of 50 users online, but I expect we'd have a normal usage by 25-30 users online at the same moment. It's an application similar to a CMS, a roleplaying community based on chats, forums and so on.

Comment: Mysql have an internal procedure to close connections when it is inactive, but the next question is, do you use the connection when page is charge? If you don't use the connection more times, close it. For this kind of page, I don't think  you have any problem with mysql, but it's depend too the configuration of your database. You can see your limite connections open directory or your mysql.exe, execute him in cmd and write this 'show variables like "max_connections";'. If you want change open your directory mysql and find my.ini or my.cnf and change the line have max_connections or add it.

Comment: You can add it: max_connections = 300